# Adding Apple Pay access in India

Tags: ios, applepay

I want to test Apple Pay for my US based application. Is it possible to check in India with the help of US based Bank account Cards?

Comment: You might wanna check this series of blogs: http://vinsol.com/blog/2017/09/07/apple-pay-on-web-integration-with-rails-1/. I worked on it inside India only.

Answer (score 1):

Currently sandbox supports Apple Pay for few countries. You need to create a sandbox account of that App Store territory, but you can test from any location.
Reference: [Apple Pay Sandbox Testing](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it possible to test it in the Sandbox environment. 
Refer here To sandbox environment testing: [Apple Pay Sandbox Testing](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/)

You'll need the following to test Apple Pay in the sandbox:

- iPhone 6 or later, iPad mini 3 or later, iPad Air 2, iPad Pro, or
  Apple Watch
- iTunes Connect sandbox tester account
- Supported test credentials

**Important:** If you mistakenly use a sandbox tester account to sign in to a production environment, like iTunes, on your test device instead of your test environment, the sandbox account becomes invalid and can’t be used again. If this happens, create a new sandbox tester account with a new email address.